# T-SQL - "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" - but they ABSOLUTELY do

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting this error, which almost always happens when you have misspecified a table so that it has different columns, or columns in a different order, from those which are selected.

In this case, I have checked, double-checked, triple-checked, quadruple-checked and quintiple-checked, and they are both completely identical. I have even gone so far as to copy and paste the column names from the table into the "select" query, so that there can be no doubt that they match.

What else could cause this error? Could it be to do with the base categories?

```
CREATE TABLE ##PChart 
(
     ColA bigint,
     ColB varchar(max), 
     ColC varchar(max),
     ColD varchar(max),
     ColE decimal(18,2),
     ColF varchar(max),
     Coll_ColA bigint,
     Collection_ColB varchar(max),
     ColG varchar(max),
     ColH varchar(max),
     ColI varchar(max),
     ColJ int,
     ColK int,
     ColL date
)

insert into ##PChart
    select 
        ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF,
        Coll_ColA, Collection_ColB, ColG, 
        ColH, ColI, ColJ, ColK, ColL
    from
```

Comment: can you post the table definition and the code of your `insert`?

Comment: Afraid not - the information is proprietary

Comment: I mean, you could anonymize the column names

Comment: post the error?

Comment: You will get no help if you dont give the information.   You are obviously missing something no matter how many times you check.  You need another set of eyes on this.

Comment: You can't post we can't help.  VTC

Comment: @Lamak anonymised data posted above

Comment: no computed columns?, identity ones?

Comment: any triggers on that table?

Comment: @Lamak some of the columns are computed in a subquery, but in the outer (correct term?) subquery, they are all just named columns.

Comment: @Lamak no - I don't believe any triggers are attached to the table.

Comment: Try dropping ##PChart first, then running what you have posted.  Maybe there is a stale instance of the table still.  Since it's a global temp table, maybe you have it in another query window somewhere with a different definition?

Comment: @Squillman - tried that - it doesn't work.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it could be to do with the base categories being wrong - I don't think this would make a difference (and I don't think they are wrong), but could that possibly generate this error? 

I can't see how, but then I can't see any other explanation.

Comment: Does it work if you use a local temp table instead of a global?

Comment: And no way you can post what you're querying from?

Comment: can you make sure about the triggers?. And by "computed column" I meant something like `CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(col1 INT, col2 INT, colX AS col1 * col2)`

Comment: @Squillman yes - that does work.  Why might that be?

Comment: @Squillman - I.e., creating it as local table instead worked.  Why might that be?  Could that be to do with user permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems something else has ##PChart locked and it has a different schema than what you're using in the posted code.  You need to find what process has a hold of it.  Global temp tables stay in scope across the entire server instance until nothing else is using it.  Check other query windows you may have open, applications processes that use your code, etc.  All processes using that table need to end before it will be released and you can recreate it with a new schema.